# Flutter Material Icon Minus

Tags: flutter

I cannot find it. Why in material design icon there is no minus icon?

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html

I can have Add icon https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IconData-class.html but why there is no minus icon?

Comment: `Icon(
            Icons.remove,
            color: Colors.deepOrange,
          ),`

Comment: Wow thanks. I feel stupid looking for substract, delete and minus

Comment: check first at - https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline

Comment: @anmol.majhail Maybe you can put answer so I can accept it

Comment: for a squared minus button similar to the `Icons.add_box` you can use the `Icons.indeterminate_check_box`

Answer (score 95, accepted):

In order to check the avail icons - you can check - https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline

Now coming to minus icon - it is present with different Name.

```
Icon( Icons.remove, color: Colors.deepOrange, ),
```

Answer (score 0):

you can edit your button/floating action button using the code given below.

```
FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Icon(
                    const IconData(0xe15b, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                    color: Colors.black),
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              ),
```